# Set it's not a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $A_{n,E}=\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}:k \ mod \ n\in E\right\}$ with $E\subset \left\{0,1,2,..,n-1\right\}$ , and $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of all $A_{n,E}$ for all different choices of n and E.Is $\mathcal{A}$ a sigma algebra ??? And if not which sigma algebra generates ???

I already proved that it's algebra but I have a hard time to prove that it's not a sigma algebra and which algebra it generates.

One of my attempts is to show that if  $A_{n,E_{i}}\in \mathcal{A}$ then $\bigcup_{n}\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{n,E_{i}}\in \mathcal{A}$

$\bigcup_{n}\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{n,E_{i}}\in \mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{n}\big[A_{n,E_{1}}\cup A_{n,E_{2}}\cup A_{n,E_{3}}\cup...\big]=\bigcup_{n}\left\{k:k \ mod \ n\in E_{1}\cup E_{2} \cup .. \right\}$.But I dont know what to do further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix a rapidly increasing sequence $(p_i)$ of primes, and let $B_i=\{k\in\mathbb N:k\equiv p_i-1\pmod{p_i}\}$. Then each $B_i$ is in $\mathcal A$, but the union of all the $B_i$ isn't in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Also if we assume that we can find sigma algebras lets say $F_{i}$, $i\in I$ with $A_{n,E}\subset F_{i}$ and then we take the intersection of all these we create the smallest sigma algebra that is generated by $\mathcal{A}$ (because we know that the intersection of sigma algebras is still a sigma algebra ??)

Comment: The intersection of any family of $\sigma$-algebras on the same set is itself a $\sigma$-algebras on that set.  The intersection of all the $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb N$ that include $\mathcal A$ as a subset is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$.  I don't immediately see a neat alternative description of that $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all $A_{n,E}$ for all different choices of $n$ and $E$.
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generates by $\mathcal{A}$. I claim that $\{n\}\in\mathcal{B}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, given the claim we have that $\mathcal{B}$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$. Observing that the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are either infinite or empty we have that $\mathcal{A}$ is strictly contained in $\mathcal{B}$. So $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra (as already noticed in the comments) and moreover the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is the power set.

---

Finally let us prove the claim: it is enough to observe that  if $n\neq 0$ we have $\{n\}=A_{n,E}\cap(\bigcap_{k=2}^{\infty}A_{k\cdot n,E}^c)$, where $E=\{0\}$. Also we have that $\{0\}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{n\}$.